# Query ODBC incomplete - missing rows that contain 'ñ'

Tags: php, sql, odbc, character

I have a connection with iSeries Access ODBC Driver - 64bits; with PHP

When I ask a query from the database, the result show certain rows, but not all, when I change the query I can see that the character 'ñ' just shows as a black weird symbol: `<?>`. Maybe my driver or PHP dont decode the special character, so it doesn't show the row, because in MICROSOFT QUERY it shows more rows.

How to decode the data coming from ODBC?

Here's my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM LIBP02.WOPINHD0 A 
LEFT JOIN LIBPGTUSR.CSPTREF0 B ON A.IVNO1 = B.INV16 
WHERE A.IVDAT8 IN 20180131 
  AND A.CUNO NOT LIKE ('TTRNS%') 
  AND A.SLSREP in ('3168 JUAREZ GLEZ HECTOR J','2417 JESUS KENNETH SANCHE','1947 LOPEZ RAMOS JAHAYRA','2174 GUTIERREZ GUERRERO F','2192 MAGAÑA CASILLAS MARC','3309 ESPARZA LEOS JOVANY')
```

Comment: What is your query?

Comment: Hello @JacobH is this:

SELECT*

FROM  LIBP02.WOPINHD0 A

LEFT JOIN LIBPGTUSR.CSPTREF0 B

ON A.IVNO1 = B.INV16


WHERE A.IVDAT8  IN 20180131

AND    A.CUNO  NOT LIKE ('TTRNS%')

AND    A.SLSREP in ('3168 JUAREZ GLEZ HECTOR J','2417 JESUS KENNETH SANCHE','1947 LOPEZ RAMOS JAHAYRA','2174 GUTIERREZ GUERRERO F','2192 MAGAÑA CASILLAS MARC','3309 ESPARZA LEOS JOVANY')